# Kubectl missing form Terraform Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform cloud to provision some k8s infrastructure .

The issue i am facing is as terraform provider for kubernetes doesn't have the flexibility  of yaml file . i need to run some yaml files using `kubectl apply` This was okay when we run from local machine but when its from Terraform cloud it errors that

```
kubectl is not installed
```

Is there a way to solve this ?

possible install kubectl on terraform cloud

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the `kubectl` binary using a `null_resource` with the `local_exec` provisioner:

```
resource "null_resource" "custom" {
  # change trigger to run every time
  triggers = {
    build_number = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  # download kubectl
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl"
  }

  # run kubectl
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml"
  }
}
```

Of course you also have to provide the target settings/credentials for `kubectl`, but that depends on your cluster provider, for example on AKS you would run `az aks get-credentials` before using `kubectl`.

Comment: Thanks Markus.. I tried that now & plan finished which did not detect any changes so no apply option.,This might be because from terraform point of view no changes in infrastructure but this inside k8s . I will continue to investigate this

Comment: that's right, but you can add a changing value to the null_resource, so it triggers every time, i updated the example.

Comment: missing triggers =, however i am getting ```(local-exec): /bin/sh: 1: ./kubectl: Permission denied``` . Have you seen this before ?

Comment: corrected. the permission denied is because the executable flag is not set after downloading. i added `&& chmod +x kubectl` to the download step to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks , As you suggested if we use ```az aks get-credentials``` we need to download this binary as well and provide the resource group , cluster name etc..
Is it possible to use  below 
```# setup to output your kubeconfig from your terraform build
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config_raw}"
  filename = "./prod-kubeconfig"
}
```
and use this file to connect to cluster  
```provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "./kubectl --kubeconfig=./prod-kubeconfig apply -f deployment.yaml"
  }
}```

Comment: No joy at all.. now its says 

```module.aks.null_resource.your_deployment (local-exec): error: stat ./prod-kubeconfig: no such file or directory```. The same code outputs the file and works fine from my local machine ,am i missing something. I don't think we can use  ```az aks get-credentials``` as for that need to ```az login``` first and not sure if that is possible at all

Comment: the path most probably is a different one. you can debug the issue by running a `ls -lah` or `find .` or similar in local-exec as well, so you see the filesystem of the terraform cloud instance. the kubeconfig output file may be in some module subdirectory.

Comment: The issue was the order of execution ..i added ```depends on``` and all worked fine Thanks again